# spotify-app under Kodi (LibreElec)

Tags: kodi, openelec, chromium, pi-1

I try to run a spotify-app

> plugin.audio.spotify-1.0.26.zip

from Marcel Veldt

under Kodi Jarvis (LibreElec - latest release).

I tried it with this howto
https://seo-michael.co.uk/how-to-install-spotify-for-kodi-beta/

I got stuck and the following point

> Select Music > Add-Ons
>   Select Spotify
>   THE ADD-ON WILL NOT OPEN
>   You will now have to back out of Kodi and check your web browser as you will need to login to Spotify
>   You must now authorise the add-on so it has access to your Spotify account
>   You should now be able to open the add-on in Kodi and have access to your
>    Spotify account 
>   Spotify is now installed and as usual the add-on can be accessed via MUSIC > Add-Ons > Spotify from your home screen.

I get to install the app, I even updated it to the latest (beta) version, I just don't get it what I do have to do after "THE ADD-ON WILL NOT OPEN".
If I want to open spotify it gives a login error:

> Login error: argument 2: :'asci' codec can't encode character u'\u0107' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)

Again, no clue.

Attempts to "authorise the add-on" like it is said in the post (http://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=265356&pid=2289336#pid2289336) failed for me.

> 1. install the spotify client on a pc with a browser
> 2. open the spotify client and accept the authentication request in the browser.
> 3. now, on the filesystem navigate to kodi userdata\addon_data\plugin.audio.spotify and copy the cache file to the same location on your pi

I have Spotify installed under Ubuntu, but I don't have a clue - where the mentioned folder should be.
Does anybody have a clue how to solve this?

As I use LibreElec I don't have a webbrowser outside Kodi so I
wanted to install chromium as workaround, and it seems like chromium is not provided via LibreElec repo at the moment
Link: h**ps://forum.libreelec.tv/thread-3846.html
Have to find another way / a chromium .zip to install via "sideload" as a workaround

Edit2: browser.chromium-8.0.104.zip install failed
Edit3: windows cache workaround for libreElec didn't work aswell for me (I still get the mentioned login error)

Comment: You can authorize it on any computer

Comment: Thank you for the statement, I guess I can stop looking for a browser and start to find a solution for that login error then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a the spotify plugin for a computer with Kodi, I signed in to spotify and a file named "**USERNAME**.cache" got created under .kodi/userdata/addon_data/plugin.audio.spotify"

I copied this file over to my raspberry and from then on the spotify plugin works.
My Pi is v1, with LibreElec7, it is slow but I just streamed my first spotify track.

PS: I am using a non-facebook spotify account